# Why does ufw block wget & python scripts?

Tags: networking, openvpn

After setting up a VPN killswitch I noticed that a few things don't work: aptitude, python scripts using requests, & wget.  (curl does work).  Does anyone know why?

My ufw settings are:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8.8.8.8                    ALLOW       Anywhere                   
8.8.4.4                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.0.0/24            
Anywhere                   ALLOW       224.0.0.0/24              
127.0.0.1                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
ff01::/16                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
ff02::/16                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
ff05::/16                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
::1                        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)               

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0          
VPN IP                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
8.8.4.4                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
8.8.8.8                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
224.0.0.0/24               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
VPN DNS IP                 ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
127.0.0.1                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0     
ff01::/16                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
ff02::/16                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
ff05::/16                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
::1                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I added a few DNS IP's so the internet connects more quickly when waking up.

The python script I am testing is just 3 lines:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
print "worked", len(r.text)
```

When I run it, `dmesg -w` I think says it's trying to run on the wireless interface:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=2605:e000:2e44:dc00:0000:0000:0000:0005 DST=2607:f8b0:4000:0800:0000:0000:0000:2004 LEN=80 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=384122 PROTO=TCP SPT=40074 DPT=80 WINDOW=28800 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Is there something I can change to make this work?

Comment: It is using IPv6. how are your routing rules for IPv6 ? Does the traffic is set to goes to the VPN tunnel for IPv6 also ?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check this?  I tried enabling forwarding in /etc/default/ufw & /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf with no luck.

Comment: I worked around this by disabling ipv6, which is ok enough for me.  I added `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`,
`net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`, and
`net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` then ran `sudo sysctl -p`